# Why does Roo generate ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean java and its aspectJ (.aj)?

Tags: spring-roo

What is this ConversionService factory bean for?

Is there any way to tell Spring Roo not to generate the java file and aspectJ, converting every service that I have.

I'm having a multimodule project, and one web application does not need all the services, hence I do not add the dependency. However, this Roo generated aj (ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean_Roo_ConversionService.aj) gets me compilation error.

Thanks!
Robert

Answer (score 0):

The factory bean creates all the converters for the Spring Roo project.

The converters are used in a few different places, the most significant is to convert domain objects to strings for use in select drop downs when one domain object has a relationship to another.

You could try pushing in the conversion service methods and overriding them to do nothing.  But I don't think that will help your situation as Spring Roo still expects to see the signature of those methods, and the signature would require the dependencies.